# Making Angular routes work with Express routes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I've got in impasse with setting Angular routes to work with Express.

I tried to do like here [Express 4, NodeJS, AngularJS routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235384/express-4-nodejs-angularjs-routing) but that did not work. The static index.html serves each time the url changes, but the Angular does not catch the partial.

In my Express I have the following code:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
app.use("*",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"app/index.html"));
});
app.listen(1337, function(){
    console.log("Server is listening on port 1337");
});
```

And in my Angular app, I have the following:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp",["ngRoute","appControllers"]);

    app.config(["$routeProvider","$locationProvider",function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
            $routeProvider
                    .when("/list",{
                        templateUrl: "/partials/users.html",
                        controller: "userListCntr"
            })
                    .when("/edit", {
                        templateUrl: "/partials/edit.html",
                        controller: "userEditCntr"
            })
                    .when("/register", {
                        templateUrl: "/partials/register.html",
                        controller: "registerCntr"
            })
                    .when("/login", {
                        templateUrl: "/partials/login.html",
                        controller: "registerCntr"
            });

    }]);
```

I don't have any errors in my browser console. The html inspector shows:
    `<!-- ngView:  -->` so the directive is kind of initialized.

And dependency list:

```
dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.x",
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.x",
    "jquery": "1.10.2",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-route": "1.3.x",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.x",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.x"
  }
```

here is my file structure:

```
--app (angular app)
   --components
   --js
   --css
   --img
   --assets
   --partials
   --index.html
--node-modules
--server.js (here express settigs are)
```

ALso, I made changes as follows to account for all static resources, but still does not work:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/app"));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/app/js'));
app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/app/css'));
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/app/assets'));
app.use('/components', express.static(__dirname + '/app/components'));
app.use('/img', express.static(__dirname + '/app/img'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/app/partials'));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('/app/index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

Please, help, because I can't find a solution. Thanks!

Comment: So, the partial pages are not rendered? And are you sure they are being loaded?

Comment: No, they are not being loaded. No GET requests in my console to partial pages

Comment: http://expressjs.com/starter/static-files.html might help

Comment: I can't figure out what you mean? Am I doing something wrong with express.static()?

Comment: Where are you saving your templates (users, edit, register, login)?

Comment: in partials folder of app directory - please, see the file structure in my question

Comment: So, what else could be wrong?

Comment: Try removing the `app.all('/*'...` route and see if it fetches the templates then

Comment: No, it does not serve the templates. Actually, it serves only index.html when i on localhost:3006 as expected. If app. all("/*) is on then it fetches index.html for all routes, but does not fetch any partials. No GET requests to partials at all

Comment: this did it for me ``app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/app"));`` in my app that was transpiled with angular CLI

Comment: 6 years later, I am working on NodeJS API setups and wrote my own blog :  https://www.sudheerkaushik.com/2021-05/Setting_up_node_backend/

Answer (score 9):

When you don't pass a path to `express.use()`, then it defaults to `/`. The proceeding rule you set for `*` is either redundant or may not even work.

Also, since you're using `html5mode`, you need to explicitly set apart routes from resources so Express doesn't try to serve up your `index.html` file for all requests.

Try this example from [Angular UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) on for size:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/partials'));

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});

app.listen(3006); //the port you want to use
```

Comment: Thanks, but that did not work. Still no GET requests and renderning of partials. I have my angular app in /app folder, so i changed your answer like this                                    app.use(express.static(__dirname+ "/app"));
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/app/js'));
app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/app/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/app/partials'));

Comment: Can you update your question with your file structure? Also, are you serving static partials or serving them via $templateCache?

Comment: I have static html partials. Thank for your help, I updated the question with file structure

Comment: Sorry, please, see my file structure (i forgot to add code tags to it)

Comment: It's been a minute since I've used Express. I see they changed the API around for version 4 and the example that UI-Router has uses version 3 syntax. I assume you're on 4?

Comment: Yes, I am on 4. SHould I change the syntax for that. The thing is that I am learning Express only 4 days. Too much info to consume. Please, help

Comment: I looked over the migration guide and I was wrong... `.use()` changed some, but not in a manner that impacts this example. Unfortunately I can't replicate your issue. I just spun up a new app that follows your app structure and even copy and pasted your server block using both Express 3 and Express 4 and they both worked.

Comment: Joshua, thank you very much for your efforts. I just found that I should add <base href="/" /> to the head in my index.html. Found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214835/angularjs-how-to-enable-locationprovider-html5mode-with-deeplinking. And it worked suprisingly. The Angular grasped the partial at last!)

Comment: By the way, may it be something to do witn angular version. What version did you use?

Comment: 1.3 and 1.4. The base issue makes sense. I just assumed it wasn't that since you didn't mention any console errors, which Angular throws when you use html5mode without a base.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everybody for help. I resolved the question by inserting `<base href="/" />` into head section of my Angular index.html. It worked for me, but as of now it's like magic and cargo coding, since I don't understand why it works :)
Found solution here: [AngularJS: how to enable $locationProvider.html5Mode with deeplinking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18214835/angularjs-how-to-enable-locationprovider-html5mode-with-deeplinking)

Comment: Its important to have the `<base href="/" />` **before** `<link>` and `<script>` tags including files and scripts in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that adding `base href=` helped me.  I have my app statically served in express and browsing directly to routes in my angular app would cause lots of

> refused to execute script because its mime type ('text/html') is not
>   executable and strict mime type checking is enabled

errors to be throw.  But adding `base href` fixed that and I can browse directly to my angular routes now.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution suggested by @kirgol of using `base href=` works fine, there is an alternative solution which might interest someone looking for simple route serve. In this solution we will not using ExpressJS routing

Simply use this

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app'));
```

instead of this

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

This way expressJS will automatically serve the index.html present at that static location & will handle the routing automatically. It will behave just like a simple http server. The moment you handle the routing using `app.all`/  `app.get` - you will have to set `base href` to tell `$locationProvider` of location from which it can match routes

Answer (score 0):

I too faced a similar situation for routing through angular components using express, this is how I was able to resolve the routing issue:

**Setup for my Nodejs Project:**

- Build an Angular Project for production and placed in the public folder.
- Created an app.js file for the express server with the following contents:

  `var express = require('express');
  var app = require('express')();
  const port = 8090;
  app.use(express.static('public'));
  app.listen(port,()=>{console.log("App working at port : http://localhost:"+port)});`

Running this loaded the Root Component only, from where I had to manually route through different pages using `routerLink`. If I instead tried to give the child components directly using URL I got a `Cannot GET/{URL}` error.

**Fix:**

- I added the `express-http-proxy` package imported as
- `var proxy = require('express-http-proxy');`
- Then added in the following line after the `app.use(express.static('public'));`
- `app.use('/*',proxy('http://localhost:'+port+'/*'));`

This fixed my issue.Apparently there is a more standard fix [Refer Link](https://angular.io/guide/universal)