# How to connect my NodeJS with my Angular (in Nginx)

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker, dockerfile

I've a repo with angular and nodejs.
I performed in jenkins:

```
# install globally
npm install -g bower
npm install -g gulp

# install
bower install
npm install

# build dist folder
gulp build
```

Now I have in my root:

```
Dockerfile.nginx  Dockerfile.nodejs  README.md  bower.json  dist  gulp.config.js  gulpfile.js  node_modules  package.json  server.js  src
```

I'm copying the dist folder inside my nginx container. So I'm hosting the angular. (with a dockerfile)

```
FROM nginx
# copy folder
COPY dist /usr/share/nginx/html/dist
```

I'm copying: `gulp.config.js  gulpfile.js  node_modules  server.js`  to my nodejscontainer. (also with a dockerfile)

```
FROM node

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/www
WORKDIR /usr/src/www 

# copy 
COPY node_modules /usr/src/www/
COPY gulpfile.js /usr/src/www/
COPY gulp.config.js /usr/src/www/
COPY server.js /usr/src/www/

 EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "server.js" ]
```

I run the 2 containers but the nginx does not communicate with the nodejs

**EDIT1:**
Start containers:

```
docker run -d -p 8888:8888 --name "nodejs" localhost:5000/test/nodejs:1

docker run -d -p 80:80 --name "nginx" localhost:5000/test/nginx:1
```

**EDIT2:** My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
http {

        upstream node-app {
              least_conn;
              server nodejs:8888 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
        }

        server {
              listen 80;
              location /dist {
                alias /usr/share/nginx/html/dist/;
               }

              location ~* /api {
              #location / {
                proxy_pass http://node-app;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
              }
        }
}
```

My server.js looks like:

```
app.get('/api/hello', requestProxy({
  url: xxx + "/hello"
}));
```

Comment: Can you share how to start those 2 containers?

Answer (score 2):

You need to expose the port of the node.js container to which nginx(angular) container will connect.
See the [Connect using network port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/#connect-using-network-port-mapping) section of docker documentation.

Update : I think, you need to configure the nginx configuration file to the node container. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25235384/express-4-nodejs-angularjs-routing) has sample nginx file related to your use case (although, not related to containers).

Edit : To map the node app with the nginx, you first need to link the node container with nginx container.

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name "nginx" --link nodejs:nodejs localhost:5000/test/nginx:1
```

When you link the node container with the nginx container, the node container's address will be saved in the /etc/hosts. So the nginx container can access the node's address from there.

So, in nginx configuration file, the nodejs will be accessible as nodejs' container address:

```
http {

        upstream node-app {
              server nodejs:8888 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
        }

        server {
              listen 80;

              location / {
                proxy_pass http://node-app;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
              }
        }
}
```

Comment: @manish Do you always need to configure nginx.conf to let nodejs and nginx work together?

Comment: PS: I am also kind of beginner in docker and nginx, so some information might be wrong.. Also, I found the following to be very helpful: http://anandmanisankar.com/posts/docker-container-nginx-node-redis-example/

Comment: I saw that post too. I tried your proposal and I have the same issue as explained  at the answer under yours. ( I don't know what I have to write here: location / ). The api is running at url:8888/api

Comment: @Jenson I'm also nginx newbie, but I think you can set alias to the angular files in the nginx configuration file and then use that path in the node app. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/29384842/3785351 So, you will also need to link nginx to node container.

Comment: I've edited my nginx.conf but still not working (see question)

Comment: Thanks, now I'm able to see my static files again. I can see url:80/dist/... (and I can see my static files), on url:80/api I can see my 'backend'. But they aren't linked. Still doing something wrong? on url:80/dist/page1 I have to see the data which is provided from my api but it isn't there

Comment: Maybe my server.js can help you?

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/) both containers as described in [@manish's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34873390/107049).

But be aware that this is the *legacy* way of connecting containers together.

---

From now on, you can use the [new docker network feature](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/) to *create a virtual network* and connect both containers to that network:

```
docker network create mynetwork
docker run -d --net=mynetwork -p 8888:8888 --name "nodejs" localhost:5000/test/nodejs:1
docker run -d --net=mynetwork -p 80:80 --name "nginx" localhost:5000/test/nginx:1
```

With such a setup, your nginx config file must use

```
server nodejs:8888 weight=10 max_fails=3 fail_timeout=30s;
```

as you now refer to other container by their name.

Comment: I will try. But it's sure I have to link my containers so it wouldn't be done automatically? (because I saw it once working in my vm) (now I'm on ec2 of amazon).

Comment: I performed your steps and when I'm going to url:80/api i see the same as url:8888/api. So that seems to work. But I'm unable to see my angular code at url/dist/index.html# (it gave a 404)

my nginx.config is has: location ~* /api { (because there is my api, am I doing it wrong?

Comment: I changed /api to /. Now I'm getting Cannot GET /dist/... at each page