# Manual refresh causes only JSON to show

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, angular, express

I'm using NodeJS server to gather data from a MySQL database, and returning it as a JSON object.

```
  app.get('/random', (req, res) => {
  var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'test'
  });
  connection.connect((err) => {
    if(err) {
      res.send(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Connected to database!");
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM test", (err, rows) => {
        if(err) {
          res.send(err);
        } else {
          res.json(rows);
        }
      })
    }
  });
})
```

Entering the URL manually (localhost:3000/random) causes the JSON object to render, which is not what I want.

However, using Angular (v4) routing, it renders the HTML as I want it, which is with the header, footer and the data inbetween. Important angular code can be seen below.

*random.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class RandomService {
  constructor(private http: Http) {
    console.log('Random service initialized!');
  }

  fetchData() {
    return this.http.get('/random')
    .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

*random.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RandomService } from './random.service';
import { Random } from '../../../Random';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-random',
  templateUrl: './random.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./random.component.css'],
  providers: [RandomService]
})
export class RandomComponent implements OnInit {

  random: Random[];

  constructor(private randomService: RandomService) {
    this.randomService.fetchData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.random = data;
    })
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

*random.component.html*

```
<h1>Random</h1>
<div *ngFor="let r of random">
  ID: {{ r.idtest }}
  <br>
  Column: {{ r.testcol }}
  <br>
</div>
```

*app-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './components/page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';
import { RandomComponent } from './components/random/random.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'random', component: RandomComponent },
  { path: 'page-not-found', component: PageNotFoundComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

*app.component.html*

```
<app-header></app-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<app-footer></app-footer>
```

I know the issue, which is I never try to render the Angular component through the server. I've tried researching, but I can't seem to find out how to do this.

TL;DR: Can't figure out how to render Angular component using NodeJS, or figure out another way around.

My issue shown in pictures:

*Accessing the random-page using routing through Angular*
[image: Angular routing]

*Accessing the random-page by manually entering the URL (or refreshing random-page)*
[image: Entering URL manually]

Comment: the API and angular url route name should differ

Comment: You should forward all your requests to `index.html` so it will let angular handle the routing

Comment: @nmanikiran Thank you! That solved the issue. Feel free to add it as your answer, so I can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All routes should be handled by serving index.html. A common practice is mounting your json api to a prefix like /api/random.
So, if you visit localhost:3000/random, your backend should serve index.html. Then, your angular application should make an api call to localhost:3000/api/random to retrieve dynamic data.

This can be done with **express standalone**:

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const api = require('./api.js')
const app = express();
app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use('/api', api) // Very important. mount your api before the all path '/*' catch 
app.get('/*', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.listen(8000)
```

api.js

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
router.get('/random' /*your random api handler*/)
module.exports = router
```

Another (better) approch would be using a **frontend http server/load balancer like NGINX in front of your nodejs api server.**. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34872979/how-to-connect-my-nodejs-with-my-angular-in-nginx)

OUT: Another thing: you should connnect to your database only one time, usually just before http server bootstrap. Then you should export your connection object and use it inside your api logic. Making a connection to a database for each request will overkill your app.

EDIT: with this pattern (it doesn't matter if with express standalone or with nginx), your SPA frontend (in your case built with angular) has the responsability to handle 404 status page.

Answer (score 1):

The URL of angular and the node API much differ both are `/random`

when you directly hit the `URL` then the node server will serve the route accordingly.

in your case change the name of the API URL.
The general convention is to prefix with the `/api/{name}` for all of your Node.js API's in this way to can avoid such issues